# Regular expressions, Greek characters and the *-quantifier doesn't work (but the +-quantifier does)?

Tags: regex, special-characters, quantifiers, character-set

I use this regular expression `[\p{Greek}]` to match any Greek character. It works as expected and matches the first Greek character on the line. However, I want to match all Greek characters that follows that first character but the *-quantifier doesn't seem to work for Greek characters.

This is my input data. First three spaces, a double quote and then a Greek or Latin string, with one or more space, ending with ", and a new line.

```
   "ξηλξλκξ λκλξλξ",
   "lkjlkj kjljl",
   "δδσασα ασδ ασδφ",
   "xxaax asdsd dsds",
   "δερεφε αδσφδσ",
```

a. `^.*?[\p{Greek}|\s]` - just matches the first space on **all** lines.

b. `^.*?[\p{Greek}|\s]+` - matches all three initial spaces, on **all** lines.

c. `^.*?"[\p{Greek}|\s]+` - matches the whole line when it is written with Greek characters

d. `^.*?"[\p{Greek}|\s]*` - matches the initial spaces and the `"` on the Latin lines and the whole line excluding the `",` at the end on the Greek lines.

e. `[\p{Greek}]*` - <del>matches **all** characters on the Latin lines, but just one at the time (in spite of the *). On the Greek lines it matches the initial spaces, one at the time, but not the first `"`. Then it matches the first word, not the space between the words,</del>

(e) is super confusing. If I do a search-and-replace using that regular expression on the string    `"XYZ NOP",` and insert `A` for everything found one at the time ("replace and find next") the result looks like this  `A  A"XAYZA NAOPA",A`. However, if I perform a "replace all", this is the result ´A A A A"AXAYAZA ANAOAPA"A,´. All the original characters remain, in spite of performing a search-and-replace, with As more or less randomly inserted.

I have no idea what is going on here.

A couple of questions here:

1. Why does ^.*? just match the first spaces in (a) and not the " in (b)?
2. Why does + and * give different results?
3. (e) - what to say!? I don't understand the *-quantifiers behaviour here.

I am using BBEdit for this. I have used BBEdit with regular expressions since the 90s and have never encountered any issues with its regexp implementation. But OTOH, I have never tried working with Greek characters before.

Comment: I don't understand https://regex101.com/r/5RtzkL/1 this matches all greek letters

Comment: In case of _e._ `[]*` you are more or less matching the _empty string_, resulting in a letter splitting of non Greek.

Comment: The `+` quantifier forces at least 1 match https://regex101.com/r/kzVS6u/1, the `*` quantifier can match 0 (or more) https://regex101.com/r/kzVS6u/1 which means zero matches at each character. So it's 7 vs 71

Comment: Now that you know the regex basics of syntax, it's a good idea to delve into quantifiers significance which is 90% of regex understanding.